# Is the funtion $f(x,y)=\frac {x^2y^2}{x^2y^2 + (y-x)^2}$ when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f((0,0))=0$ continuous at $(0,0)$ and is this differentiable?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Is the function  $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac {x^2y^2}{x^2y^2 + (y-x)^2} & \text{ , when } (x,y)\not=(0,0)\\0&\text{ , when }(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$  continuous at $(0,0)$ is this differentiable?
For differentiabily I have arrived at a point $\lim_{(h,k) \to 0}\frac {h^2k^2}{(h^2k^2+(k-h)^2)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$. But no conclusion from here and not also for continuity.

Comment: You may use polar coordinates for such functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach to the point $(0,0)$ along the path $y=x+mx^2$

Then ,

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+mx)^2}{(1+mx)^2+m^2}=\frac{1}{1+m^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

if $A$ is any real number other than unity, then if $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ along the curve:
$$
A(y-x)^2 = x^2y^2(1-A)
$$
we have
$$
\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2 + (y-x)^2} = \frac1{1+\frac{(y-x)^2}{x^2y^2}}=A
$$